# understanding how values of variable changes in angular?

Tags: angularjs

I was just going through the angular-openlayers-directive and found an example **[HERE](http://tombatossals.github.io/angular-openlayers-directive/examples/024-center-bounds-example.html)**.

Now i have a angular question , you can see the code as below:

```
  var app = angular.module("demoapp", ["openlayers-directive"]);
        app.controller("DemoController", [ "$scope", "olHelpers", function($scope, olHelpers) {
            angular.extend($scope, {
                offset: 0,
                cairo: {
                    lat: 30.0047,
                    lon: 31.2586,
                    zoom: 10,
                    bounds: []
                }
            });

            $scope.$watch("offset", function(offset) {
                $scope.cairo.bounds[0] += parseFloat(offset, 10);
                $scope.cairo.bounds[1] += parseFloat(offset, 10);
                $scope.cairo.bounds[2] -= parseFloat(offset, 10);
                $scope.cairo.bounds[3] -= parseFloat(offset, 10);
            });
        }]);
```

I am highly interested in knowing what happens in the below lines of code:

see inside the object literal ciaro:  `bounds: []` , and then check out the below `$watch`:

```
$scope.$watch("offset", function(offset) {
                    $scope.cairo.bounds[0] += parseFloat(offset, 10);
                    $scope.cairo.bounds[1] += parseFloat(offset, 10);
                    $scope.cairo.bounds[2] -= parseFloat(offset, 10);
                    $scope.cairo.bounds[3] -= parseFloat(offset, 10);
});
```

now i inserted the following test code to see what exactly is the values of offset and if it changes:

```
setTimeout(function(){
        console.log($scope.offset);
}, 3000);
```

i always set `0` as the value , so why the $watch on focus than ? it never changes , also how does the values of `bound[0]` , `bound[1]` , `bound[2]` , and `bound[3]` change ? i mean thier values are not `0` ? How come ? can anybody explain that ?

**EDIT** ::

Just did a little bit more testing and found the following:

Even if i remove the following code:

```
$scope.$watch("offset", function(offset) {                    
          $scope.cairo.bounds[0] += parseFloat(offset, 10);
          $scope.cairo.bounds[1] += parseFloat(offset, 10);
          $scope.cairo.bounds[2] -= parseFloat(offset, 10);
          $scope.cairo.bounds[3] -= parseFloat(offset, 10);                     
});
```

and i add the following test code:

```
setTimeout(function(){
                    console.log($scope.cairo.bounds[0] + ' ' + $scope.cairo.bounds[1] + ' ' + $scope.cairo.bounds[2] + ' ' + $scope.cairo.bounds[3]);
                }, 3000);
```

I get the following in the console:

```
30.76009536132813 29.766565657014212 31.757104638671876 30.242264176913594
```

Where on earth are thes values coming in `bounds[]` from ?

Comment: Nothing in the posted code modifies the offset. But what you put in the scope is intended to be read and modified by the view. So you probably have a piece of code in the view that modifies it.

Comment: `Nothing in the posted code ` , well i have posted a like too http://tombatossals.github.io/angular-openlayers-directive/examples/024-center-bounds-example.html .. i am making a example in vanilla js to check if just initializing the map with a lat and lon actually also adds a `extent` to the map , http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/apidoc/ol.geom.Circle.html#getExtent , will keep this thread updated for more .

Answer (score 1):

The answer lied in the source of angular-openlayers-directive , check out the below source code:

```
if (isArray(scope.center.bounds)) {
    var extent = view.calculateExtent(map.getSize());
    var centerProjection = scope.center.projection;
    var viewProjection = defaults.view.projection;
    scope.center.bounds = ol.proj.transformExtent(extent, viewProjection, centerProjection);
}
```

So we define `bound:[]` and the above code works its magic , the below line:

```
var extent = view.calculateExtent(map.getSize());
```

returns an array and yes if a map is initialized with `lat` and `lon`, the `extend` , is set automatically.